# PlayN WebGL perfomance for canvas

Tags: performance, webgl, playn

WebGL is really slow.

100 sprites per frame - ok,

1000 sprites per frame - need optimization,

10000 sprites, fps drop down from 40 to 20fps.

I do not need 3D at all. I do not need filters, shaders, lights and other 3D stuff. I need just fast 2d canvas (without pixel smoothing) with ability to render png's and render shapes for debug (lines, bars, circles).  Is there any possibility to exclude WebGL from PlayN engine and switch to HTML5 Canvas? (I suppose it will be much more faster than WebGL.)

Comment: It'd be good to have some data to analyse when you assert that you have a performance problem. How did you measure your performance? Got some test code that you can post?

Comment: I'm guessing it's slow because it's drawing those 10,000 sprites each in a separate WebGL draw call...

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with WebGL. WebGL is fast. Nor does it have to do with PlayN. You are asking to race the Indy 500 using an SUV. The SUV is never going to be comparable to specialized race cars. However, if you have to drive over unknown terrain, and take kids to the soccer game, and pick up groceries on the way home, the SUV is going to be a much better choice.

In the case you describe, the slowness is neither WebGL calls nor Canvas.drawImage calls, it's the fact that PlayN does a full affine transform multiplication to compute the current transform for every sprite on every frame. This is what you want 99% of the time, because most games have many fewer than 1000 sprites on screen at once, and prefer the flexibility of being able to manipulate those sprites any way they please.

If you really need 10,000 sprites, and you're not just trying to use a scene graph engine as a particle system, then use an `ImmediateLayer` layer and call Surface.drawImage to draw your images in the position they need to be, and keep the math that determines their position to a minimum.

Comment: For example, I can easily draw 10,000 sprites (from a single texture) at 60 FPS in Chrome on a Mac laptop using WebGL, as long as I use Surface and don't create 10,000 layers. If you use layers, it bogs down around 1200 sprites. Try it yourself here: http://samskivert.com/playn/perf-test/